# In iphone 5s location of movies is not showing which is received from airdrop

Tags: ios, iphone, airdrop

My friend sends a movie from his iPhone to mine via AirDrop, and I accept the option to receive the file. However, the movie is not showing on my device.

Comment: Please add a few more details of your issue so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Photos and videos that are shared with Air Drop are saved to iPhoto's.  Movies are shared to the Albums section.